# Book about a boy who is ejected from his spacecraft during a game of hide and seek

Tags: story-identification, books

So all I can remember is that it's about a boy who is ejected out of his spacecraft when he plays hide and seek. He later lands on a planet with a scorching sun and is then captured by the aliens of the world, then towards the end the two (boy and alien) get in a raft and escape to somewhere.

Comment: Off to a good start but we could use a few more details, such as when you may have read it or when you think it was published. If you haven't already, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: read it in 2009-2010 but seemed older, it was memerable because the environment was very colorful with giant trees and lots of life. I think the cover had a giant tree with people holding hands and hugging it around.